# C: Why can't I change the top binary tree node in a non-main method?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I think this is more of a pointer problem than a binary tree problem. As an exercise I was re-creating a guessing/learning game in C using a binary tree. I had a method, traverse, which would go through the tree and ask questions, etc. This method, when it found a non-existent node would ask the user for input to create a node, hence the learning part. When I do this however I get corrupted data. This is a recreation of the relevant code:

```
Node * getnew(char *msg, char isAns)
{
    Node *nnew = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nnew->ID=clock();
    nnew->guess=msg;
    nnew->isAns=isAns;
    nnew->yes=0;
    nnew->no=0;
    return nnew;
}
void traverse(Node **top)
{
    char ques[128] = "ok";
    char ans[128] = "ok";
    printf("Node is null\n");
    printf("Put in a question and answer to yes condition\n");
    printf("Enter question: ");
    while(!fgets(ques,128,stdin));
    printf("Enter answer for yes condition: ");
    while(!fgets(ans,128,stdin));
    printf("Check ques: %s\nCheck ans: %s\n\n",ques,ans);
    make_question_answer(top,ques,ans);
    fprintf(stdout,"\ncheck in method: top: %s\n\n",(*top)->guess);
    fprintf(stdout,"\ncheck in method: top->yes: %s\n\n",(*top)->yes->guess);
}
void make_question_answer(Node **change, char *ques,char *ans)
{
    Node *top = getnew(ques,'n');
    Node *a = getnew(ans,'y');
    top->yes=a;
    top->no=(*change);
    *change=top;
}
int main()
{
    Node *top=0;
    traverse(&top);
    fprintf(stdout,"\ncheck: %s\n\n",top->yes->guess);
}
```

using make_question_answer() in main will successfully change top, and it works in traverse but it won't last in the jump back to main. It points to corrupted data as seen with fprintf. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: oops nevermind that. I changed the name I thought it might be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In getnew() you're assigning nnew->guess to a stack variable. Consider allocating memory for the string and using strncpy() or some other mechanism to fill in the newly allocated memory.

Comment: I used `char * expstrcpy2(char * a)
{
char *b = malloc(sizeof(a));
char *d = b;
while(*b++ = *a++);
return d;
}`. Technically both answers given are correct I'm giving it to you because the other other mentioned strdup() which is exclusively linux. if arrays can decay to a pointer why would they be governed by scope? I need to use `malloc()` if I want it stored dynamically or on the heap?

Comment: Notice that the pointer originates from either ques[] or ans[], local variables that, upon traverse() exit, will no longer be valid in any other scope. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_dangling_pointers

Answer (score 2):

I think what's actually happening is that you're storing pointers to local character arrays instead of copying the strings.  In your `getnew` function, copy the string like this:

```
nnew->guess = strdup(msg);
```